# Functions are not valid as a React child while trying to render a button on condition

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to render two different buttons based if the user is logged in or not but I'm getting this error for a few hours, what is causing it?
I get the props from a different file and everything is wired up using react-redux.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import {MenuItem,NavDropdown,NavItem,Navbar,Nav,Button} from "react-bootstrap";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { signIn } from "../actions";

class Header extends Component {
  static contextTypes = {
    router: PropTypes.object
  };

  renderContent() {
    switch (this.props.fetchUser) {
      case null:
        return;
      case false:
        return (
          <Button bsStyle="success" onClick={this.props.signIn}>
            Login
          </Button>
        );
      default:
        return (
          <Button bsStyle="success" onClick={this.props.signOut}>
            Logout
          </Button>
        );
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Navbar inverse collapseOnSelect>
          <Navbar.Header>
            <Navbar.Brand>
              <a href="/">React-Bootstrap</a>
            </Navbar.Brand>
          </Navbar.Header>

        </Navbar>
        <ul>{this.renderContent}</ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps({ auth }) {
  return { auth };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps,{ signIn })(Header);
```

Comment: what is the error you get?

Comment: what error do you get ?

Comment: The error is the title of the post : Functions are not valid as a React child while tryinf to render a button on condition

Answer (score 3):

You are not calling the function.

```js
<ul>{this.renderContent()}</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks, It works, but now when I call the login prop nothing happens, while if I render it normally inside the render method it works, what could be?

Comment: `renderContent` is not binded then it has no access to `this.props` as far as I see, you can use arrow function so the function access the props. `renderContent() {}` --> `renderContent = () => {}`

Comment: Sorry, it is not very clear for me, should I change my renderContent function to an arrow function?

Comment: Yes, I think so